# How to use openui5 in my asp.net core 2.0 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, sapui5

I'm building a backend application with asp.net core 2.0, backed by a mssql database.

To speed things up I want to use the openui5-library https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/

I created the database-model and have all my HTTP-actions saved as controllers to access the data with JSON-Models.

My question is how do I display the "webapp/index.html" when i start the application (routing etc.) and is it generally possible to use openui5 in a asp.net core 2.0 application?

Thanks :P

Answer (score 0):

You can download the openui5 runtime from [openui5.org](http://openui5.org/download.html) and load it locally and mention the `sap.ui.core.js` path in index.html.

```
<script src="./resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.layout"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
                >
```

Comment: I already did that but how do I display the "webapp" folder and where should it be located? I only get to display the mvc-views...